# Query formula Multiple Columns using "Where", "AND", and Torow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have multiple sheets in data google sheet, let's both named is sheet 1 and sheet 2. In sheet 1, I have three columns as below:

[image]

And in sheet 2, I have three columns in below:

[image]

If I want to filter sheet 1 based column ID Primary, example the ID Primary is 54f94c2f. If i paste the ID Primary to column ID Primary (sheet 2), then on sheet 2 it will output the column as follows:

[image]

i have created formula for column 2 of sheet 2 (B2) and it is not worked. the formula is:

=torow(unique(filter(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2)),1)

The result is (still wrong):

[image]

The question is how the formula to fix it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternate Answer

As the question states in the subject, here's a way to `QUERY()` using "WHERE", "AND" and `TOROW()`  formula

##### Try:

```
=TOROW(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:C,"Select B where A='"&A2&"' and B is not NULL"))
```

##### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `UNIQUE()` function. Try-

```
=TOROW(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2),1)
```

Comment: @AkhmadFahrudhin Glad to know! If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.